# Why is material with 'Displacement and Bump' set only showing 'bump' displacement in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, displacement

### Problem

I am trying to apply a static displacement map to a plane. Even though I am using the Cycles renderer, and I have configured the Principled BSDF shader to use "*Displacement and Bump*," I am still not seeing any variation in the plane's geometry.

- Windows 10 version 2004
- Blender 2.83.0
- Cycles Renderer

  - Cycles Feature Set: Experiemental

### Actual Result

It appears that the plane has a bump map effect, but the displacement aspect isn't working.

### Expected Result

The plane should have both a bump map and displacement map effect, where the geometry of the plane is being modified by the black and white displacement vector that's being fed into the material output node.

### Additional Details

Here's the wood texture I'm using

[image]

Here's a preview of the plane. It's flat, despite having the bump texture on it. The displacement isn't actually modifying the plane's geometry, like I'd expect it to.

[image]

[image]

Here's what my node editor looks like:

[image]

Here are my material settings:

[image]

Comment: If the input is  a height-map, you should use a 'Displacement' rather than a 'Vector Displacement' node.  And.. (not relevant to there being no displacement at all)..  sRGB .jpg is not the best format for the map.

Comment: I was trying to convert the color image into a greyscale, using the ColorRamp node, and then feed that into Vector Displacement, since the standard Displacement node doesn't support integration with the ColorRamp node. Is that not a good way to go about handling displacement?

Answer (score 1):

Does your plane have enough subdivisions? A flat plane with only one face obviously can't be displaced so you need to add some geometry in edit mode or by using a subdivision modifier before the displace modifier

Comment: I was wondering about that, honestly. Although I figured that the whole point of displacement maps is that you are modifying geometry without adding any additional geometric detail.

Comment: I tried adding a subdivision surface modifier, but that didn't help the displacement.

Comment: Try 'Adaptive' subdivision. that will be pixel-based, and subdivide according to visible resolution in the render.